# EXCEL COUNTIF with 2 AND Parameters

Tags: excel, countif

I need the syntax for a CountIf where 2 parmeters must be fullfild.

Count the Number of Persons who has a Partner AND Children

Here's an example:

[image]

I tried this to solf the problem

`=COUNTIF(3:3;"Partner")`

`=COUNTIF(2:2;"Children")`

But this does works

`=COUNTIF(AND((3:3;"Partner");(2:2;"Children")))`

Comment: You want COUNTIFS() with an `S` it will allow you to use two or more criteria

Comment: If it works, what's the problem?

Comment: I got problems with comparing the strings. Thanks Scott !

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

=COUNTIFS(2:2,"Children",3:3,"Partner")